# PHP array_merge multi-nível. Como fazer?

Tags: php, array, merge

Eu tenho a seguinte `array`:

```
        $arrIni["ENV"]="US";   
        $arrIni["sap_db_server"] = "192.xxx.x.xx";

        $arrIni["local_db_server"] = "localhost";
        $arrIni["local_db_username"] = "root";

        //Default settings
        $arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["UserTypeID"]=4;       
        $arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["LocalizationID"]=1;
        $arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["LangLabels"] = array();
        $arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st1"]="st1.php";
        $arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st2"]="st2.php";
        $arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st3"]="st3.php";
```

Estou usando a função [merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) com a array `$setParam`

```
$setParam["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st3"]="st3_V2.php";
```

da seguinte maneira:

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r(array_merge($arrIni,$setParam));
echo "</pre>";
```

Esse é o resultado obtido:

```
Array
(
    [ENV] => US
    [sap_db_server] => 192.xxx.x.xx
    [local_db_server] => localhost
    [local_db_username] => root
    [arrEnvSettings] => Array
        (
            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [st3] => st3_V2.php
                )

        )

)
```

Esse é o resultado desejado:

```
Array
(
    [ENV] => US
    [sap_db_server] => 192.xxx.x.xx
    [local_db_server] => localhost
    [local_db_username] => root
    [arrEnvSettings] => Array
        (
            [UserTypeID] => 4
            [LocalizationID] => 1
            [LangLabels] => Array
                (
                )

            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [st1] => st1.php
                    [st2] => st2.php
                    [st3] => st3_V2.php
                )

        )

)
```

Não entendo por que a função *merge* está apagando o conteúdo do array `[arrEnvSettings]`. Segundo a documentação ela deveria sobrescrever somente o valor `[st3]` passando de `st3.php` para `st3_V2.php` . `"...Se os *arrays* dados têm as mesmas chaves string, então o último valor para uma chave irá sobrescrever o valor anterior ..."`.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, o `array_merge` serve para unir dois `arrays`, de acordo com os índices. Se for numérico, ele junta os dois arrays, reordenando os índice.
Se for um índice nomeado, ele vai substituir pelo `array` passado no segundo parâmetro.

Para a operação que você está realizando, eu recomendo utilizar as funções `array_merge_recursive` ou `array_replace_recursive`.

Exemplo de `array_merge_recursive`. Ele vai unir recursivamente os índices multidimensionais:

```
$a = ['nomes' => ['Wallace', 'Miguel']];
$b = ['nomes' => ['Randrade', 'Guilherme']];

array_merge_recursive($a, $b);
```

O resultado será:

```
  [
     "nomes" => [
       "Wallace",
       "Miguel",
       "Randrade",
       "Guilherme",
     ],
   ]
```

Observe agora a diferença usando a função `array_replace_recursive`. Diferentemente da `array_merge_recursive`, ela vai substituir de acordo com os valores dos índices, independente de ser numérico ou não.

```
 array_replace_recursive($a, $b);

  [
     "nomes" => [
       "Randrade",
       "Guilherme",
     ],
   ]
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar um exemplo Wallace? Mais pra fins de curiosidade(minha hehe). Pode ser no ideone ou phpfidle mesmo.

Comment: Sim, sim... Estou resolvendo um pau aqui no sistema, mas vou postar

Comment: funcionou com `array_replace_recursive($arrIni,$setParam)`. A função `array_merge_recursive($arrIni,$setParam)` vai retornar o valor antigo e o novo. Ou seja vai pegar a `array [st3]` e vai inserir uma array de 2 resultados.

Comment: `echo "<pre>";
        print_r(array_replace_recursive($arrIni,$setParam));
        echo "</pre>";`